# preg_match error message

Tags: php

```
preg_match("/[\]/",'',$body);
```

I use preg_match but I have this error here

Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 3

What's wrong here I can't find it

```
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

                    function clean_string($string) {
                        $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
                        return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
                    }

                    $email_message .= "Full Name: ".clean_string($_POST['full_name'])."\n";
                    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($_POST['email'])."\n";
                    $email_message .= "Telephone number: ".clean_string($_POST['telephone'])."\n";
                    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($_POST['comments'])."\n";


                    $mail             = new PHPMailer();
                    $body             = $email_message;
                    $body             = str_replace('\\', '', $body);

                    $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
                    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                       // enable SMTP authentication
                    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                      // sets the prefix to the servier
                    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";           // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
                    $mail->Port       = 465;                        // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
                    $mail->Username   = "hanem@gmail.com";      // GMAIL username
                    $mail->Password   = "hinadk";       // GMAIL password

                    $mail->SetFrom('from-email@domain.com', 'First Last');

                    $mail->Subject    = "Imperia";

                    $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatidble email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

                    $mail->MsgHTML($body);

                    $address = "hanem@gmail.com";
                    $mail->AddAddress($address, "To Name");

                    if(!$mail->Send()) {

                        echo "<font color='red'> Message error </font>". $mail->ErrorInfo;
                    } else {
                        echo "<font color='red'> Message sent </font>";
                    }
```

there was    eregi_replace("[]",'',$body);

but I had a another error for that reason i change it to preg_match

Comment: What you are trying to match? I like [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're escaping the last bracket but not the first. To match backslash, you can do:

```
preg_match('/\\\\/', '', $body);
```

From  your edit, it appears you're trying to remove backslashes from `$body`. In this case, you would need to use [preg_replace](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). However, since your doing a simple search and replace, you'd be better off just using [str_replace](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
str_replace('\\', '', $body);
```

Comment: there was eregi_replace("[]",'',$body);

but I had a another error for that reason i change it to preg_match

Comment: `eregi_` functions are deprecated so you can't use those. However, `preg_match` doesn't do replacement, only search. Therefore, you should use `preg_replace` or `str_replace`.

Comment: sorry bro, what should I write here preg_replace("[]",'',$body)?

Comment: Yes, if you must use `preg_replace`, you would do `preg_replace('/\\\\/', '', $body);` However, as I stated, if you don't need regular expressions (which simple search and replace doesn't), it's better to just use `str_replace`

Comment: thanks for replying but after that I have this error SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. What wrong here I just updated my code. sorry for a lot of question

Comment: That's a completely different issue. You'll need to post a new question for that. Please remember to checkmark this answer (checkmark in upper left).

Answer (score 0):

The `\` is used to escape special characters, so you are escaping your closing bracket and you have an opening bracket without the closing one, leading to an error.

What do you want to match exactly, the `\` character?

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter of the preg_match is the matches array, in this way you overwrite the $body variable's value by an array.
for replacing use preg_replace instead of preg_match
$body = preg_replace("/[\]/",'',$body);
and use escaping in regular expression